# Export data from DataTable into Excel 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

Datatable the values are

Stalin-- 001 and Micheal-- 002 . but generating excel i getting output as

[image]

While generating into excel the "0" are not coming.how to solve this type of scenerios.

Code:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string filename = " ExportedData.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
    dgGrid.DataBind();

    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);       
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Paste your code as a **text**, not as an image..

Comment: ok @TimSchmelter,how will i get that file?

Comment: @SonerGönül but then SO would not format the code in Italic Times New Roman!

Comment: @gpaprinceantony: That was just a joke, deleted my comment since you have now provided the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store/update the data in the DataTable to the following format: **="001"**

Example:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("A");
        dt.Columns.Add("B");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name", "No" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Stalin", "=\"001\""});
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Micheal", "=\"002\"" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a problem with your code. 
Its an issue with your excel configuration hiding the prefixed zeros.

1.On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the View tab.

2.Do one of the following:

To display zero (0) values in cells, select the Zero values check box.

To display zero values as blank cells, clear the check box.

Comment: thats i understand,but i may not configure anything in excel file.but i need to display the data as 001.

Comment: Sounds like a cell format issue, you will need to use quoted strings for that cell value.. you may have to do some parsing for the rows where you expect `001` can you change the datagridview datatype for that particular row to be a string and not an int

Comment: Maybe set the content type to be text?
    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the content types of your columns in the datatable before linking it to your datagrid.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
```